# "Had not gone" or "didn't go" and "every night" in conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

> You’re always tired. If you **had not gone** to bed so late every night, you **wouldn’t be** tired all the time.

Or:

> If you **didn’t go** to bed so late every night, you wouldn’t be tired all the time.

I'm not sure which one is correct.
“All the time” and “every night” point out that this situation happens always, both past and the present time. Which one I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the second one - the first explicitly refers to events in the past

> had not gone

whereas the second having the future tense of:

you **wouldn’t** be tired

refers to a situation that is expected to occur in the future.

If the first was instead:

> You’re always tired. If you had not gone to bed so late every night **last week**, you wouldn’t be tired right now.

for example, that would be okay, as all of "last week" is in the past and the tense matches.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase **did not go** is a backshift to the past tense from **do not go** to express a situation contrary to the reality.  You *do* go to bed late every night. That is your general practice.

> You **go** to bed late every night.
>   -- No, I **don't**!  I **do not go** to bed late every night.
>   Yes, you **do**.  You **do go** to bed late every night. If you **did not go** to bed so late every night, you would have more energy during the day.